# Predicate Logic Question - Let T(a) be "a is a teacher" and S(a) be "a is a student" - What is "Every Teacher is also a student"

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I had this question on a previous exam and am trying to understand where I went wrong. My attempt for this question yielded me: $$\forall x(T(x)\land S(x))$$
My logic in thinking this was the solution was due to the word **Every** in the statement. This must mean it was a universal quantifier for $x$.  And since $x$ was a teacher and also a student, I ended up with the previously stated solution.

I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: Your attempt reads: everyone is both a teacher and a student.

Comment: Consider the difference between your suggested translation and $\forall x (T(x)\to S(x)).$ Changing the latter to disjunction form may help the comparison.

Comment: ∀x(T(x)→S(x)) would it translate to: If x is a teacher, then x is also a student.

Comment: Not exactly, because your suggested translation doesn't incorporate any quantification. Try again?

Comment: If I was incorporate the universal quantifier into the statement: For all x, if x is a teacher, then x is also a student?

Comment: 1. Yes; try to rewrite it more organically (more *natural* language), then compare your final sentence with the exam's given statement.   2. You should still explicitly understand the difference I asked about in my first comment.

Comment: Every x is a student if x is also a teacher? - Let me rewrite this: Every person is a student if that person is also a teacher.

Comment: This is correct too, but not quite what I was hinting for. Anyway, just compare these two sentences that you now have with the exam's given statement, and make an observation among these three sentences.

Comment: They seem to be very much similar since I can easily just change the order of my previous translation to be the same as the exams statement! Thank you for the help, have a good day tomorrow!

Comment: No worries: to be clear, the three statements, together with $\forall x (T(x)\to S(x)),$ are equivalent. Again, you should think about the difference between these and $\forall x(T(x)\land S(x))$ and what Bonnaduck wrote.

Comment: In your statement, it is not possible for a student to not be a teacher.  Or for anybody to not be a teacher. Or for anybody to not be a student.